# Atomically increment a field using SubSonic 3 ActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, subsonic, subsonic3, subsonic-active-record

I'm tring to increment a field in a MySQL database using SubSonic 3 ActiveRecord.  In SQL, this is what I'm after:

```
UPDATE people SET messages_received=messages_received+1 WHERE people_id=@id_to;
```

I tried the following, but it didn't seem to work (messages_received always seemed to be 1):

```
_db.Update<person>()
    .Set("messages_received").EqualTo(x => x.messages_received == x.messages_received + 1)
    .Where(x => x.people_id == idTo)
    .Execute();
```

This did work:

```
string sql="UPDATE people SET messages_received=messages_received+1 WHERE people_id=@id_to";
var q=new SubSonic.Query.QueryCommand(sql, _db.Provider);
q.AddParameter("id_to", idTo);
q.Provider.ExecuteQuery(q);
```

So I have a solution, but I'm just wondering if it's possible to do this without resorting to plain SQL?

Answer.  For reference, based on Rob's suggestion below::

```
_db.Update<person>()
    .SetExpression("messages_received").EqualTo("messages_received+1")
    .Where<person>(x=>x.people_id==idTo)
    .Execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the old query tool for this and use "SetExpression":

```
db.Update("MyTable")
   .SetExpression("messages_received +1")
   .Where("people_id")
   .IsEqualTo(1)
   .Execute();
```

That's freehanded - but hopefully you get the idea :)

Comment: Cool, thanks Rob, yep got the idea, posted the working version above.