# SubSonic3 SetExpression problem

Tags: subsonic3

Next SubSonic3 query gives me an error:

```
Db.Update<Tag>()
    .SetExpression("Popularity")
    .EqualTo("Popularity+1")
    .Where<Tag>(x => x.TagId == tagId)
    .Execute();
```

Error: failed: System.FormatException : Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

The sql that is generated is ok, but the collection of parameters contains two parameters that need to be set.

```
UPDATE [Tagging].[Tag] 
SET Popularity=Popularity+1
WHERE [Tagging].[Tag].[TagId] = @0
```

One of the parameters set @up_Popularity to 'Popularity+1'. Since this is the first parameter being set, sql triese to assign this string 'Popularity+1' to an integer.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Db.Update<Tag>()
    .SetExpression("Popularity = Popularity + 1")
    .Where<Tag>(x => x.TagId == tagId)
    .Execute();
```

This should work ... but I think it's for wholesale updates. Not sure. Your best bet is to use our CodingHorror:

```
new CodingHorror("UPDATE Tags SET Popularity = Popularity + 1 WHERE @1", 
  tagId).Execute();
```

Comment: Rob, this seems to throw an error saying 'Cannot resolve symbol Where'. Apparently, SetExpression returns a Setting instance and not an Update instance.

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429381/atomically-increment-a-field-using-subsonic-3-activerecord addresses the same problem, but the proposed solution doesn't work either (then I get the error above in my question).

Comment: Is the CodingHorror solution the only way to do it, Rob? Can it be fixed so that your first example would work?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be amazed if that was supposed to work. When I need to have a string evaluated as part of the SQL (and not by SubSonic) I almost always end up having to use a [CodingHorror](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/CodingHorror).

However,  you should be able to do this by using a separate query. Something like:

```
Db.Update<Tag>()
  .Set("Popularity")
  .EqualTo(Tag.SingleOrDefault(t => t.TagId == tagId).Popularity + 1)
  .Where<Tag>(x => x.TagId == tagId)
  .Execute();
```

Comment: Well, like this it'll probably work, but you have to go twice to the database.

Comment: I think my query should definetely work, but because subsonic creates two sql parameters, it doesn't work.